# Monitor a programs data transfer

Tags: networking

Is there a way to monitor what data a program sends and receives from the internet? So for example if you have a game and it takes some information from a server, since the program would have to be told the information, is there a way of recording that and reading it? I've read a few questions similar but they were all focused on how much data was transferred. I what to know what data is being transferred

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Fiddler (for HTTP traffic) or Wireshark (for all traffic).

Comment: thank you kind person of the internet, I will check these out and come back and vote

Comment: seems to be the job alright but I can't make any of this out at all. Not as simple as I thought it was going to be

Answer (score 0):

```
extView infoView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.traffic_info);
String info = "";

info += "Mobile Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getMobileTxPackets() + " packets\n");

info += "All Network Interface:\n";
info += ("\tReceived: " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalRxPackets() + " packets\n");
info += ("\tTransmitted: " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() + " bytes / " + TrafficStats.getTotalTxPackets() + " packets\n");

infoView.setText(info);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();

mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes(); TextView RX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.RX);

TextView TX = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TX);

long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes()- mStartRX;

RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));

long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()- mStartTX;

TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
```